# Android: <include/> layout crashes application on landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to use the include tag to reuse the layout code from the activity_main.xml and contact_details.xml during landscape mode. I would like to display the activity_main on the left and contact_details on the right. But the application crashes when I switch to landscape mode.

This is the coding for the activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddContact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="Add Contact" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the coding for contact_details.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvContactDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the coding for my layout-land/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#A3A3A3"/>

<include layout="@layout/contact_details"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any tips for resolving this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: Change the name of the layout you want to include, don't name it activity_main too; it might be a circular reference.

Comment: @Adinia Thanks. You solve my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Adinia for the suggestion. It was because I should not call back the same Layout name, which is activity_main.xml. This is the main cause of the crash. it might be a circular reference as Adinia had stated. Thanks again. By the way, I am only allowed to accept my answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml ,contact_details.xml you are using

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

instead that try using

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

If not post you logcat report

Comment: This is not a reason for a crash; at worst, the layout will not look as expected.

Comment: @Adinia I guess you were right.But I have a question wont the xml have different R values?if yes then der is no prob in using the same name right?Do correct me if am wrong

Comment: In landscape, the system knows only one activity_main.xml file, so trying to include it in itself will crash; you have no mean to tell it you want to acces the file from the default folder.

Comment: so using layout-land/activity_main.xml wont help?